# Sending the output of a docker container as a response to a post request in flask

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to build an application which takes a post request and runs a docker container which executes a shell script.I want to send back the output of the shell script as a response to this post request.For example the output of the shell file is "**hello world**" and It should be sent back as response to the post request.Here is the code

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get('/run')
def test():
    return 'running'

@app.post('/run')
def handle_request():
    
    lang='python'
    language = request.data
    code=language.decode('utf-8')
    if lang=='python':
        file = open('input.py', 'w')
        file.write(code)

    else:
        file = open('input.cpp', 'w')
        file.write(code)
    output=dockersandbox()
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

import docker
import os
def dockersandbox():
    image = 'myimage'

    client = docker.from_env()

    container = client.containers.run(
        image=image,
        volumes={os.getcwd(): {'bind': '/container/files', 'mode': 'rw'}},
        remove=True,
        stdout=True
    )
    output = container.decode('utf-8')
    return output
```

Here the expected response for the post request is "**helloworld**" as the output of the shell file execution is "**helloworld**" but when I send a post request from postman I get this "**Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000**".I have separately ran that dockersandbox function and it works as intended and gives the correct output.I have also tested by sending only a string like **"Test"** as ouput of the dockersandbox function without implementing any docker container logic and code,in that case it gives the correct response for that post request,this issue happens if I implement this docker client logic in the dockersandbox function.I am using python's docker library to implement the docker logic and run the container.

Comment: Are you trying to run this script itself inside a container?  Are you actually getting up to the point of trying to invoke the Docker API at all?  Do you _need_ to run the subprocess in a separate container, or can you add the shell script to the main application image and just run it using the Python `subprocess` module?

Comment: @DavidMazev Thanks for your reply,Yes I am trying to run the shell script itself inside the containter,I need to run it in a docker container because I need a sandbox environment and don't want to cause any issues to my actual server/host machine.